# Xamarin.iOS Google Ads Targeting

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ads, adsense

I want to integrate Google Ads in my app, but I am stuck when it's time to load the request and get the Ad.

What I need is to pass targeting parameters to load an Ad related to my user's search.

I'm trying to load a `SearchRequest` for displaying a `SearchBannerView`, but no method seems to match my needs. The `LoadRequest` methods of the `SearchBannerView` do not accept `SearchRequest`. They only accept `Request` and no cast exists between those two classes.

However, the original Google docs says it's possible: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/search-ads-for-apps/ios/

Here is my code:

```
this.banner = new SearchBannerView(AdSizeCons.Banner, new CGPoint(0, 0));
this.banner.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
this.banner.AdSize = AdSizeCons.Banner;
this.banner.AdUnitID = this.AdService.AdMobUnitId;
this.banner.AdReceived += this.AdReceived;
this.banner.RootViewController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;

var request = new SearchRequest();
request.Query = ((GoogleAdViewModel)this.DataContext).Query;

// my request isn't accepted
this.banner.LoadRequest(request);
```

Has anyone succeed to make `SearchBannerView` load something using the Google Ads component from Xamarin?

It's for an iOS app and I'm using this component: https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleiosmobileads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/197740#Comment_197740).

It was an issue in the binding library, the type `SearchRequest` had a wrong base type (`NSObject` instead of `GADRequest`).